# Writing bytes in a pdf

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

I am getting a response for an API in form of bytes.

```
let a = "JSHDHHFHFHHFKFLLFLDMDMDMDMMSKKW==";
```

I want to write this into a pdf file. 
The approach I have taken till now is to convert it to binary using atob library. Then I convert it to a Uint8Array and write to a file using fs.writestream. When the file write completes it gives me an output of unidetified type.

````
%
1 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 141/N 20/Length 848/Type/ObjStm>>
stream
xUmoâ8þ+óm[U½ø%/ÎiU  ÈÂr]º¸ë¢|ð/)`©ý÷7ã´vK·HQ2gÆÏ3À@)ÀcHBd@*P§¤ Î U8GC8q3È_C¦x¦¤øU8Oà3$c¨*Æ/æK?óÝ7÷¸5Á`
íÆ-Ð4?¶Î¬Çï²3Ù=0YØÑ8èm0.ÍÆUî1  ¢ý+3í²©¶Î6"ûº5~º?½»®Fzçôºº¹!ÙO>=¸ÑÜigºù÷¼ÏyDqÇIè?*Ê¥J!âB)ÿ§ ½àøÌÝDÇþ{;ü2¹ê5®¯û¶.'1Í«ÚÊZã@$~4GØÿda0vº®½Íª6H-­àZ&Lo?jõÃáÁIÐë¦¼=¬õªñ+¿T¿oòë³S$±Þ±ð³wzm^ú²ÍNÏ¨J[Bß6iEði³´eµYíi»þ|@ÜÂþ½©ÐÁx/iãt©ÑÕÌT¯LKNy³µ]½dzHÞÈì¿ì¯Á¢ùï2Ta°<b¬HDNµ¤¹êþø2Äz=WTâ÷hg õr¡æQîI²2xj;÷æÁe[|Ó à±¦#b\:IEÌ,ékvª_]ØÌ´v×,Mû$êCô¯hêgþp»DEäÁ4óàµ#Å¡v$§vDx¤y yR;qè#Q;ByÇíÓ{Z6»£UÛªlsÎ»
ÜÙ>5»[pÍÎ_§tíO;Û¬u}¢ñm·µYv|mJÓ`)_<×Ç%²½ªZ×<^ôJûÍ\þÒ{Â£Þð'"u?ÅÅ!\{þÈ~?âEF¡xàBxÏþigX]¿quu&^/ú¶ìÅ½IüþvZj<§A_½ñ¾ëº5¯ÖÄ.²?ãsÁY_1ñ±Á 1ÚUvó¶
£Ü-Ms1~ÑÛº#Hÿìr$ö¤ÿ²}R
endstream
endobj
22 0 obj```

When I am trying the response on online editor it gives me the write response.

The code I have used till now.

let encodedPDF = JSON.parse(d).Resp_Policy_Document.PDF_BYTES;
var bin = atob(encodedPDF);
var binaryLen = bin.length;
var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) 
{
var ascii = bin.charCodeAt(i);
bytes[i] = ascii;
}
let writer=fs.createWriteStream('Last.pdf');
writer.write(bin);
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you get is [Base64 encoded](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11ta8CYQFIgMoqTVXlBDvfbkpboe2PdSmcAdP4Iasy9I/edit?usp=sharing). That's a pretty common way for APIs to pass information. The giveaways? the equal signs at the  end, and the use of ASCII uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, `+`, and `/`.

So, you need to decode it that way.  Use something like this

```
const pdfBinary = Buffer.from(a, 'base64');
```

The contents of this buffer, I guess, are a pdf document. You should write it directly to a file without trying to convert it to a text  string.